# SwiftUI: List shifts items down when tapping on Navigation Link

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Whenever I tap on a NavigationLink in a List after the list is scrolled a bit, it appears that the list shifts down temporarily. Please see the following video (simulator with "Slow Animations" enabled):

[image]

Here's my code:

```
struct SearchView: View {
    private static let navTitle = "Title"

    @EnvironmentObject var locModel: LocationViewModel
    
    @ObservedObject private var searchModel = SearchViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            if searchModel.isLoading {
                ProgressView()
                    .navigationTitle(SearchView.navTitle)
            } else if searchModel.results.isEmpty {
                Text("No results.") // TODO
                    .navigationTitle(SearchView.navTitle)
            } else if let total = searchModel.total, let lastPage = searchModel.lastLoadedPage {
                List {
                    Section {
                        ForEach(searchModel.results.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                            SearchResultRow(searchModel.results[i]).id(i)
                        }
                        
                        if searchModel.results.count < total {
                            HStack {
                                Spacer()
                                ProgressView()
                                Spacer()
                            }.task {
                                await load(page: lastPage + 1)
                            }
                        }
                        
                    } header: {
                        if let locName = locModel.location?.name {
                            Text("**\(total)** results near **\(locName)**")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle(SearchView.navTitle)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            Task.detached { await load() }
        }
        .onChange(of: locModel) {
            Task.detached { await load() }
        }
    }
    
    private func load(page: Int = 1) async {
        if let loc = locModel.location {
            await searchModel.load(location: loc, page: page)
        }
    }
}

struct MinyanSearchResultRow: View {    
    let searchResult: SearchResult
    
    init(_ searchResult: SearchResult) {
        self.searchResult = searchResult
       
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink {
            DetailView(searchResult: searchResult)
        } label: {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Hello there")
                }
            }        
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    let searchResult: SearchResult
                    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely because the navigation bar size changes. You can see it when you swipe back

Comment: When I add a navigation bar to DetailView it still shifts down. Is there a way for the view to have its own nav bar so no shifting is needed?

Comment: Don't use the large style navigation on your first view, use modal navigation instead of push. Many options. Could also just be because you're reloading the model while navigation. The `.onChange(of: locModel) {` looks sus (and is entirely unnecessary if you implement a proper observable model)

Comment: If you remove that if/else block and just display `List` as a direct child of `NavigationStack` do you see the same issue? If that fixes it, maybe reimplement your loading and empty views as full-size overlays of `List`. The visual impact will be the same but you're removing the creation of `List` out of the drawing decisions made by SwiftUI on every state change, if that makes sense.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen How do I connect the two models together then if I don't use the onchange?

Comment: I’m pretty new to SwiftUI so I’ll take any tips I can get

Comment: Note, you probably should be using `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject`

Comment: This problem happens even with Apple-provided example code for how to use `NavigationLink` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink#Link-to-a-destination-view - just add more items to the list and it'll shift just as the OP shows in their post.

Answer (score -3):

Lots of mistakes: shouldn't be using view model objects, make `View`s instead. The awaited async funcs are supposed to return something not be voids, usually stored in an `@State`. Initing an `@ObservedObject` like that is a memory leak, there is no ownership. Too many `if`s is inefficient, instead, define the view once and use an if on the params (or refactor logic into a computed var). `onAppear` with `Task.detached` looks like a mistake, in SwiftUI it is `.task`/`.task(id:)` to use async/await. The most serious mistake that will crash is `ForEach` is a `View` it's not a for loop, it needs to be supplied `Identifiable` data or supply a unique identifier key path, you can't use `id: \.self` because that is not a valid identifier key path, so change:

```
ForEach(searchModel.results.indices, id: \.self) { i in
    SearchResultRow(searchModel.results[i]).id(i) // this [i] will crash if the results change in size.
}
```

to

```
ForEach(searchModel.results) { result in
    SearchResultRow(result) // this [i] will crash if the results change in size.
}
...
struct SearchResult: Identifiable {
...
```

Hopefully all of these suggestions help!